# Server Events not got fired in Virtual Directory

Tags: .net, iis-6

I am having a sample application developed in .Net. 
I had created a Virtual directory for that. 
i want to access my application in another system ( The source code will not be in that system ),using my local IP.

Like this.....
http://xxx.xx.xx.120/Development/Login.aspx

Now its working in another system. But the server events are not firing ( for ex - The data not getting saved in  database ). I had given the connection string in my aspx page itself

How to fix this...

Comment: You need to tell us a bit more. What do you mean by "server events"?

Comment: Server Events - using local IP, i am accessing my application in another system, if want to save some data to database means its not saved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS, make sure it's more than just a Virtual Directory. It has to be an Application within IIS. [This](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis-7/) may help, if that is indeed your problem.